# SQL sum from different columns from different tables in one result

Tags: sql, sum

I want  with SQL a result that shows me the SUM of two different columns  from two different tables, and the is one extra table for customer names.

**Table 1**
Customer_ID,
Customer name

**Table 2**
Customer_ID,
Amount_Debt,
Amount_Debt_paid

**Table 3**
Customer_ID,
Amount_Open_Orders

I want as a result a table with the following columns

Customer_ID,
Customer name,
TotalAmountDebt = Table2 SUM(Amount_Debt - Amount_Debt_paid),
TotalAmountOpenOrders =Table3  SUM(Amount_Open_Orders),

I have tried for hours several different queries, but I don’t get the correct result, I hope someone has a solution for me, I think it’s simple but I am missing here something.

Kind regards,

Björn

Comment: You have to use 'left join', do you have in all the 3 tables the same  Customer_ID?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum before aggregation:

```
select c.*, t2.*, t3.*
from customers c left join
     (select t2.customer_id, sum(t2.amount_debt) as amount_debt,
             sum(t2.amount_debt_paid) as amount_debt_paid
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.customer_id
     ) t2
     on c.customer_id = t2.customer_id left join
     (select t3.customer_id, sum(t3.Amount_Open_Orders) as Amount_Open_Orders
      from table3 t3
      group by t3.customer_id
     ) t3 
     on c.customer_id = t3.customer_id;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have tried your code but get some errors, see my answer.

Comment: @Björn . . . (1) Use valid table aliases.  (2) If you want to show such code, an answer is not the best place to put the code.  You can edit your question.  You could edit my answer.  Or perhaps best, you could set up a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I changed the aliases and now it works fine. Thank you very much for your help. Kind regards Björn

Answer (score 0):

i filled in the suggested code, and now i'm getting an error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'.

Code:

```
enter code here
    SELECT        dbo.FI101CUSTOMER.*, dbo.FI101DEPT.*, dbo.HB101ORDER.*

    FROM            dbo.FI101CUSTOMER left JOIN 
    (select dbo.FI101DEPT.CUST_ID, SUM(dbo.FI101DEPT.BETRAG -            
    dbo.FI101DEPT.BETRAGZAHLUNG) as Value1
    from dbo.FI101DEPT
    group by dbo.FI101DEPT.CUST_ID
    ) dbo.FI101DEPT
    ON dbo.FI101CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = dbo.FI101DEPT.CUST_ID left join
    (select HB101ORDER.CUST_ID, SUM(HB101ORDER.bruttovkwert) as    Value2 
    from HB101ORDER
    group by dbo.HB101ORDER.CUST_ID
    ) dbo.HB101ORDER
    ON dbo.FI101CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = dbo.HB101ORDER.CUST_ID;
```